# mongodb: Unable to fetch results from $project and $eq

Tags: mongodb

below code first joins two collections on one field and tries to filter values on other field.

```
db.zeroDimFacts.aggregate(
{$lookup:{from:"zeroDim",localField:"Kind",foreignField:"Model", as:"EmbedUp"}},
{$project: {"EmSub":"$EmbedUp.Sub","Result": {$eq:["$Type","$EmbedUp.Sub"]}, "type":"$Type"}})
```

Please check the below output of the code. Even though 'EmSub' & '$Type' are having equal values, it does not show up in 'Result' field.
If it is because 'EmSub' is displayed as array, how do I compare only value containing in that array?

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "EmSub" : [ 
        "Fruit"
    ],
    "Result" : false,
    "type" : "Fruit"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "EmSub" : [ 
        "Fruit"
    ],
    "Result" : false,
    "type" : "Fruit"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(3),
    "EmSub" : [ 
        "Fruit"
    ],
    "Result" : false,
    "type" : "Fruit"
}
```

Comment: Try $eq:["$Type","$EmbedUp.Sub.$"]

Comment: @AmiramKorach: Got the below error:
assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.",
 "code" : 16410
} : aggregate failed

Comment: Sorry. try: "EmSub": {$first: "$EmbedUp.Sub"} and in comparison $eq:["$Type", {$first: "$EmbedUp.Sub"}]

Comment: @AmiramKorach:  It also gives me error, assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$first'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13

Comment: I think $first is used in $group which may not be applicable for $project. However, I'm not sure about this.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes you're right. Can't you use group and first inside it?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can we use $eq in $group?
 "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unknown group operator '$eq'", "code" : 15952

Comment: If not, you can project after the group

Comment: This is revised query, however, the results field still shows false for all fields.
db.zeroDimFacts.aggregate(
{$lookup:{from:"zeroDim",localField:"Kind",foreignField:"Model", as:"EmbedUp"}},
{$group: {_id:"$Kind","EmSub":{$first:"$EmbedUp.Sub"}}},
{$project: {"EmSub":"$EmbedUp.Sub","Result": {$eq:["$Type","$EmSub"]}, "type":"$Type"}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unwind the array to compare with its elements like this:

```
db.zeroDimFacts.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"zeroDim",localField:"Kind",foreignField:"Model", as:"EmbedUp"}},
{$unwind: "$EmbedUp"},
{$project: {"EmSub":"$EmbedUp.Sub","Result": {$eq:["$Type","$EmbedUp.Sub"]}, "type":"$Type"}}]);
```

It can give you more than one result for a single zeroDimFacts _id, however you can group them again

```
db.zeroDimFacts.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"zeroDim",localField:"Kind",foreignField:"Model", as:"EmbedUp"}},
{$unwind: "$EmbedUp"},
{$project: {"EmSub":"$EmbedUp.Sub","Result": {$eq:["$Type","$EmbedUp.Sub"]}, "type":"$Type"}},
{$group: {_id: "$_id", EmSub: {$push: "$EmSub"}, Result: {$push: "$Result"}, type: {$push: "$type"}}}]);
```